# Objective C, NSXML parser delegate methods don't work after 4.3 update

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

It worked just fine before I updated iOS4.3
After that, the delegate methods for NSXML parser never get called...
Is there anyone having this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem: I am parsing a local XML file and fore some reason this XML file disappeared from my project during my upgrade to Xcode 4. This was no problem for testing on my iPhone, i think it was cached somewhere so the file did still exist and could be parsed. But the simulator couldn't find it anymore so the parsing delegate methods didn't get called..

(If you are parsing an XML file somewhere on the web, you should check your internet connections)

Comment: I am receiving the XML file from internet and checked the contents using NSLog. When parser called, the delegate method doen't get called...